# reading in ifstream file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a method that should read in a file called "Fruitdictionary.txt" and then print out the contents (a list of strings)... but instead it prints out "0x7fff5fbff838".

Here is the code:

```
void Words::readdictionary(){
    ifstream file_ptr1;
    file_ptr1.open("fruitdictionary.txt", ifstream::in);
    string temp;
    while (file_ptr1>>temp){
        dictionarylist.push_back(temp);
        if (dictionarylist.size() == dictionarylist.capacity()) {
            dictionarylist.resize(dictionarylist.capacity()+1);
        }
    }
    cout << &dictionarylist << endl;
};
```

Comment: `cout << &dictionarylist` Well, you ask it to print the address of a variable, so that's what it does.

Answer (score 3):

`&dictionarylist` takes the address of your list and prints *that*.

Instead, do something like

```
std::copy(dictionarylist.begin(), dictionarylist.end(), 
      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Or a loop

```
for (std::string const& s: dictionarylist)
    std::cout << s << "\n";
```

PS: No need to resize your list (assuming <strike>`std::list`, `std::deque`,</strike> `std::vector` etc. was used). Standard library containers do memory management themselves, and `push_back` will grow the allocated memory as required.

A slightly cleaned-up take:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Words {
    void readdictionary();
    void printdictionary();
  private:
    std::vector<std::string> dictionarylist;
};

void Words::readdictionary(){
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("fruitdictionary.txt");
    dictionarylist.insert(
            dictionarylist.end(),
            istream_iterator<string>(file), {}
        );
}

void Words::printdictionary(){
    using namespace std;

    copy(begin(dictionarylist), end(dictionarylist), 
            ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}

int main()
{
    Words words;
    words.readdictionary();
    words.printdictionary();
}
```

Comment: Not only is there no need to resize the vector manually, the way he is doing it provides behavior which I can't imagine is desirable.  Empty strings which are not from the file are placed in the vector at regular decreasing intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming dictionarylist is vector you cannot print a vector like that in C++. 
You can print it this way

```
for(int i = 0; i < dictionarylist.size(); ++i) {
    cout << dictionarylist[i] << endl;
}
```